# Strings copied continuously despite having reinitialized for every different object

Tags: java, string, list

```
private List<String> longStr = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
private List aList = null;
private String [] noRow = null;
private static int arrayCtr = 0;

try {
CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new   FileReader(inputFilePath),';');
    if((aList = reader1.readAll())!= null){
int outer= 0;
String aTemp;
for (int counter= 0;counter <aList.size();counter++){
       noRow = (String[]) aList.get(counter);
       for (int j = 0; j < noRow.length; j++){
        aTemp = noRow[j];
        copyArray(aTemp);
       }

    private int copyArray(String aTemp){
    longStr.add(arrayCtr, aTemp);
    //System.out.println(arrayCtr);
    arrayCtr++;
    return arrayCtr;
}
```

from the extract,every String from aList will be copied into noRow array->aTemp->longStr List.I integrated this function with JButton called "read".everytime I clicked the button for diff files as an input,strings will be added continuously ie not generating new List for each diff files.for eg if a file has one element,this will be copied finally into longStr thus index will be 0,but if a diff file has 4 elements,this will be added to index no 1 and so on instead from starting from 0 again.what did i miss here?and how can i remove all elements in the longStr List after each jbutton event?

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code more readably - and to be honest, I'm finding it hard to understand the question. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the program would really help.

Comment: You will have to be clear on what you want... I'm unable to understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: noRow holds String elements from aList n starts from 0 till the next new column,then starts back to 0.i need to store them in continuous no. of array.so aTemp copy each elements of noRow into longStr(with cont. index).the prob is when a file contains an element,it copied to longStr and longStr.get(0) will be that element.but when i open another file,elements are copied into longStr starting from longStr.get(1) ie append and the element from other file is still there.

Comment: Thanks, it got much clearer now.

Comment: @max.thx 4 the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add at the beginning to clear the list each time:

```
longStr.clear();
arrayCtr = 0;
```